# Making Symbology Scales same in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, symbology, scale

I am using two sets of data, 'Part' and 'Total'. The part set is what you would think, a fraction of the total. Part = 13 , Total = 29.

I want to overlap this data on a map using Graduated Symbols but my problem is the 'Total' quantitiy is much greater than the 'Part' quantity. This makes my graduated symbols different scales and gives a false visual representation.

Even though both tables have different quantities, how can I make it so, visually, the symbols are still accurate to true quantity?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  There used to be a downloadable tool that would allow you to copy symbology exactly as-is from one layer to another (which you'd then modify to change the colors etc.) - I used to use it to do similar tasks to what you're attempting.  Unfortunately I don't have it anymore and I don't recall its name (probably something like "Copy Layer Symbology", but I did get it from the Esri website back in the day.